# Wie kommt es zu einem wechselnden Genus beim Stammnomen "-mut"?

Tags: etymology, gender

Sowohl *die Demut* als auch *die Wehmut* (*fem.*) kommen von *der Mut* (*mask.*). Die meisten anderen Mut-Wörter sind maskulin.

- Wie und wann kam es zu dieser Änderung?
- Gibt es weitere Beispiele, die der gängigen Regel widersprechen, dass das Geschlecht eines zusammengesetzten Nomens immer das des letzten Teilnomens ist?

Comment: weiteres beispiel: ["Die Anmut"](http://canoo.net/inflection/anmut:n)

Comment: @Takkat: Mut ist in meinen Augen kein Suffix. Ich habe es zu Stammnomen geändert, bin aber für weitere Vorschläge offen

Comment: ... stimmt. Ich habs bei mir auch geändert.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In der Tat variiert das Genus der Wörter mit dem Stamm „-mut“ stark. Zwar überwiegt das Maskulinum, aber es gibt durchaus auch nicht wenige Feminina, und sogar ein Wort, bei dem beide Genera vorkommen:

- **Maskulin:** Bekennermut, Edelmut, Frevelmut, Heldenmut, Hochmut, Kampfesmut, Kleinmut, Lebensmut, Löwenmut, Mannesmut, Missmut, Opfermut, Unmut, Wagemut, Wahrheitsmut, Wankelmut, Übermut
- **Feminin:** Anmut, Demut, Freimut, Großmut, Langmut, Reumut, Sanftmut, Schwermut, Wehmut
- **Maskulin und feminin:** Gleichmut

Als Erklärung schreibt C. Scholz dazu:

> Das variierende Genus der mut-Komposita erklärt sich daraus, dass
>   das alte **muot** [...] über ein doppeltes Genus verfügte [...]<sup>(1)</sup>

Daraus erklärt sich auch, dass es altdeutsche Vornamen mit der Endung „-mut“ sowohl für Mädchen (Almut, Dietmut) als auch für Knaben (Hartmut, Helmut) gibt.

Die Regel, dass das Kompositum das Genus des letzten Teilnomens erhält, ist also eigentlich nicht gebrochen. Nur heute kennen wir aber nur noch einen maskulinen „Mut“.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> **Cosima Schulz** (2007): Genuszuweisung im Deutschen. ZSM Studien Institut für Deutsche Sprache und Literatur, Universität Köln: *S. 16*

Comment: Wow, wieder was gelernt. Dass Freimut, Hochmut und Großmut feminin sind, wusste ich nicht. Da wär ich bei Jauch glatt durch die Millionenfrage gehagelt.

Comment: @chirlu: Danke, hab's korrigiert.

Answer (score 3):

Kleine Ergänzung: Das alte Wort "muot" verfügte nicht über ein doppeltes Genus, vielmehr handelt es sich in den zweiten Silben von "Demut" usw. um eine Ableitung von "muot", nämlich "müete", und dieses Wort ist Femininum.

Comment: Nach [Lexer](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/Lexer/?sigle=Lexer&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=LM03286) gab es `muot` as Maskulinum und als Neutrum, `müete` sei der Plural. Gibt es für das Femininum eine Referenz?

Answer (score 3):

Zum zweiten Teil Deiner Frage: in diese Richtung gehen Zusammensetzungen mit '-teil'. Während 'Teil' alleine maskulin oder Neutrum sein kann, sind zumindest manche Zusammensetzungen eindeutig einem Genus zugeordnet: der Anteil, das Hinterteil. 'Vorderteil' hingegen kann wie das Grundwort mit der oder das verwendet werden.